# libGDX object random diagonal movement

Tags: java, android, libgdx

kilobolt.com day six of the Zombie Bird tutorial:
Following the code, can someone explain to me how to make it so that when the bird is falling it will also move to either side randomly (Diagonal) till it reach the ground, and without it going behind the screen boundaries?

I managed to make it move randomly to either side by making a random variable equal to velocity.x (Bird Class), but my problem is that the bird crosses the screen and I just want it to choose a place to land (and get there in a straight line from the top) between the screen boundaries.

P.S The bird starting to fall from y = 0, and x = random.

P.S2 At first I tried putting in the random variable (1,136) the screen width, but it seems that the bird treat its position as (0,0) when it first appear so any positive number in the random variable will only push it to the right.

Comment: so you have to do a little math, you know the boundaries of your gameview, 0 < x < 600  (or something like that) and with this knowladge you have to calculate the max angles your bird can fall

Comment: The bird is falling correctly if it's not changing its x. But if I want a random diagonal fall, how should I calculate it? The bird starts at a random x and end (when it reaches the ground) at a random x... If it starts at x = 40 and y = 1 (always y = 1)of the gameview, the bird object treat this position as its x = 0 and y = 0. Now when I add the random (-x to move left, +x to move right) variable that makes the bird move to either side, how should I limit the movement to not go behind the gameview's boundaries?